# Display message depend on v-on:click in vue

Tags: vue.js

I want to dispay my ip address depend on click botton in vue.

Here is my code

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"> 
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue- 
resource/0.1.13/vue-resource.min.js"></script>

<div id="my_view">
    <button v-on:click="greet">origin</button>
    <p>{{ message }} </p>
</div>
<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#my_view',
    data: {
       message: ''
    },


    methods: {
        greet: function (data) {
            this.$http.get('http://httpbin.org/ip', function (data) {
                // set data on vm
                this.$set('message', data.origin)

            }).error(function (data, status, request) {
                // handle error
            })
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

But when i click button, nothing display.

In console, print this:

```
vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, 
or primitive value: message
```

How to fix it?

Vue version: 2.5.17

Comment: `this` is not set in a bare `function`. Use an arrow function. Also, `$set` should take three arguments. You're leaving out the first.

Comment: @RoyJ Well, I don't know how to write code depond on your describe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this follow instead

```
this.$http.get('http://httpbin.org/ip', (data) => {
  // set data on vm
  this.$set('message', data.origin)      

}).error(function (data, status, request) {
  // handle error
})
```

Comment: I have a try. But it seems like message variable is wrong.              `vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: message`

Comment: you don't need to use [`$set`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set), `this.message=data.origin` is the good way, `$set` use in array or object target

Comment: It's ok. Thanks.

Comment: To use set correctly, first argument should be a context, so code should look like: `this.$set(this, 'message', data.origin)`. But it is correct, that `$set` should be used only for specific cases, when reactivy does not work as expected, e.g. dynamically created arrays of objects or multiple level nested objects, that were not declared initially in component's data.